# why scrollView is not working smoothly in some of android devices?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-scrollview, android-checkbox

I am working on an application which is using scroll view. In some devices scroll View is working fine But some devices like HTC desire (which are using lower versions of android) is not smooth in scrolling. layout is using check box in the bottom (margin 20 dp from bottom) and when I try to scroll from that particular area it is not working but in other device like micromax A110 it is working fine... why is it happening any Idea ?

Thanks

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/mDrawer"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@color/drawerColor"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#4000"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/searchHeadingTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/search"
                android:textColor="@color/drawerHadingsColor"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
                android:layout_width="190dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:alpha="2"
                android:background="#5fff"
                android:hint="@string/search"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/searchButtonImageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:alpha="2"
                android:background="#5fff"
                android:src="@drawable/search_dark" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#4000"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/chooseProductCategoryHeadingTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/chooseProductCategory"
                android:textColor="@color/drawerHadingsColor"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox_radio"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:text="@string/cakes"
                android:textColor="#EBE5E5"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox_radio"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:text="@string/cupcakes"
                android:textColor="#EBE5E5"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox_radio"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:text="@string/cookies"
                android:textColor="#EBE5E5"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/checkBox4"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox_radio"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:text="@string/highTea"
                android:textColor="#EBE5E5"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox_radio"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:text="@string/doughnuts"
                android:textColor="#EBE5E5"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox_radio"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:text="@string/chocolates"
                android:textColor="#EBE5E5"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox_radio"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:text="@string/macaroons"
                android:textColor="#EBE5E5"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#4000"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/advanceFilterForGiftingTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/advanceFilterForGifting"
                android:textColor="@color/drawerHadingsColor"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".65"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/OccasionTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/occasion"
                    android:textColor="@color/drawerNormalTextColor"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".35"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/OccasionSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:background="#0000"
                    android:gravity="right" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".65" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/drawerCloseArrow"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:background="@drawable/left_arrow_home"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/relationTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/relation"
                    android:textColor="@color/drawerNormalTextColor"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".35"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" >

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/relationSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:background="#0000"
                    android:gravity="right" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".65"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/deliveryDateTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/deliveryTime"
                    android:textColor="@color/drawerNormalTextColor"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".35"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dateSelectionTextView"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_drawer_spinner"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/dropdown"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="SELECT DATE"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/datePickerLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <DatePicker
                android:id="@+id/datePicker"
                style="@style/datePickerStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:calendarViewShown="false"
                android:endYear="2100"
                android:startYear="1900" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="#4000"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/shortbyTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/shortby"
                android:textColor="@color/drawerHadingsColor"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_weight=".6"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/priceRatingRadioGroup"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/priceRadio"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/price"
                        android:textColor="@color/drawerNormalTextColor"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/ratingRadio"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/rating"
                        android:textColor="@color/drawerNormalTextColor"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                </RadioGroup>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".6" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/refineButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="@drawable/drawer_button"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="@string/done"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/clearAllButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="@drawable/drawer_button"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="@string/clearAll"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: it is not smooth in scrolling or the bottom view is not showing?

Comment: I have Posted my XML.... I m having problem with few devices only